# Add additional field in fluentd for windows logs

Tags: elasticsearch, fluent, fluentd

We have Windows AD logs that we send to ElasticSearch (`winlogbeat->fluentd->Elasticsearch`).

Is it possible to add addtitional field in fluentd based on regexp of other field?

What I want to do:

If I have field `event_data.TargetUserName=PC-NAME$` -> I add field `event_data.logonType=Computer`

If I have field `event_data.TargetUserName=Username` -> I add field `event_data.logonType=Human`

And then send it to Elasticserach.

One trick is to regexp data with *'$'*, and other trick is to add new filed.

Can anyone tell me is it possible?

Here is part of my fluentd conf file for windows logs (it's very simple):

```
<match winserver.**>
  @type elasticsearch

  hosts http://elasticsearch.test:9200
  logstash_format true
  time_key ttw
  time_key_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z"
  remove_keys ttw
  logstash_prefix winserver.test
  request_timeout 15s

  <buffer>
    @type memory
    flush_interval 10s
  </buffer>
</match>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share your current fluentd conf file? so we can see various options we can try.

Comment: I added part of my fluentd conf file to original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in [filter_record_transformer](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/filter_record_transformer) for your purpose.